# Why Occur ANR Broadcast of Intent message on android?

Tags: android, android-intent

Android policy if broadcast work over 10 second, occur ANR dialog.

so, I think my broadcast work over 10 second. because many work this broadcast.

my broadcast when `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` on my device.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   String action = intent.getAction();

   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   int iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ?-1: activeNetwork.getType(); //null check

   if (action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
      new getPubIp().execute(); //Execute AsyncTask

      ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      if (iNetworkType == connectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET) {//connect ethernet
          EthernetConnectTimeDB ethernet;
          ethernet = new EthernetConnectTimeDB();
          ethernet.start();  //DB Insert work.

          SystemClock.sleep(500);  // sleep
          MainActivity.display("value", "value", value"); //display UI
      }
   }
}
```

this receiver , many work. DB work, display work, asynctask work.

how to fix occur ANR dialog on android?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A broadcast receiver needs to be VERY fast.  You have about 2 seconds, then your app is killed.  If you need longer than that, you need to start a Service and do it there instead.  A decent rule of thumb is that if you need to start a thread or AsyncTask for any reason, you need to start a Service.

Secondly, you should NEVER sleep on a BroadcastReceiver.  That happens on the main thread.  You will freeze your app, and likely cause just this problem.

Third-  you're accessing a static function on MainActivity?  That's almost assuredly REALLY WRONG.  For it to actually send data to the main activity that way, you'd have to be holding a static instance of it which is a memory leak.  Its something that should never be done.

You need to study up on how to write a BraodcastReceiver correctly, you broke just about every rule there is.